# VB6 failing to consume a C# library which dynamically loads assembly from byte array

Tags: c#, load, .net-assembly

I have a c# library which loads a plugin assembly using the Assembly.Load(byte[]) method. The plugin has to be loaded from its bytes array rather than a path. 
The library and plugin and all its dependencies are loaded correctly when the consuming app is a .Net app.
However this fails when the consumer is a VB6 app.
I get DllNotFoundException exception in loading some of the plugins dependencies/dlls.
How can I fix this?

Comment: well - VB6 knows absolutely nothing about .net, so that could be a problem. the main problem, however, would be using VB6 in 2019. is it a given constraint (and if so, why exactly?), or might you do something about it?

also: without you providing any code, there can be no help with your code.

Comment: Yes VB6 is still around and a definite consumer!

Answer (score 1):

An update on this for future references...
In the wrapper library for COM use, we subscribed to the AssemblyResolve event which is raised when a dependent .Net assembly could not be found, this event would contain the assembly name, so we handled the event correctly.
Also in our COM wrapper library, we did a DllImport("kernel32.dll") to overwrite the SetDllDirectory and append extra search path to be able to find native dependent assemblies.

These 2 solved the problem.